# How to replace all instances of a sub-sequence in a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I currently use this code:

```
""" Replace all occurrences of subsequence a with b in list l """ 
def replace_subsequence(l,a,b):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if(l[i:i+len(a)] == a):
            l[i:i+len(a)] = b
```

Example:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> replace_subsequence(l,[2,3],[4])
>>> l
[1, 4]
```

Is there a more efficient and/or elegant way to do this ?

Comment: `for i in range(len(l)):` could be shortened to `for i in range(len(l) - len(a)):`

Comment: Sure, but I was thinking more along the lines of not constructing the list in memory for each replacement, but only at the end. Or maybe even a c implementation.

Comment: the data objects will always be `int`, I assume?

Comment: How do you want to handle overlapping matches?

Comment: The same as in my example. However, I was also hoping for this to be a general discussion, in case other people need a function like this. It might also be an interesting example to learn how to write efficient python scripts in general. So if you have a solution which handles it differently by all means write up an answer.

Answer (score 6):

To improve efficiency, you can use the [Boyer–Moore string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)  when searching for a sublist in a list

Code ([credits](http://en.literateprograms.org/Boyer-Moore_string_search_algorithm_%28Python%29))

```
def match(pattern, list):
    matches = []
    m = len(list)
    n = len(pattern)

    rightMostIndexes = preprocessForBadCharacterShift(pattern)

    alignedAt = 0
    while alignedAt + (n - 1) < m:

        for indexInPattern in xrange(n-1, -1, -1):
            indexInlist = alignedAt + indexInPattern
            x = list[indexInlist]
            y = pattern[indexInPattern]

            if indexInlist >= m:
                break

            if x != y:

                r = rightMostIndexes.get(x)

                if x not in rightMostIndexes:
                    alignedAt = indexInlist + 1

                else:
                    shift = indexInlist - (alignedAt + r)
                    alignedAt += (shift > 0 and shift or alignedAt + 1)

                break
            elif indexInPattern == 0:
                matches.append(alignedAt)
                alignedAt += 1


    return matches

def preprocessForBadCharacterShift(pattern):
    map = { }
    for i in xrange(len(pattern)-1, -1, -1):
        c = pattern[i]
        if c not in map:
            map[c] = i

    return map

if __name__ == "__main__":
    matches = match("ana", "bananas")
    for integer in matches:
        print "Match at:", integer
    print (matches == [1, 3] and "OK" or "Failed")

    matches = match([1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2,3 , 4, 5, 6])
    for integer in matches:
        print "list Match at:", integer
    print (matches)
```

Answer (score 1):

It definitely isn't elegant, but I'm wondering if converting to strings and using string.replace would perform better if your data is as simple as in the example...

```
def strx(l):
    return str(l).strip('[]')

def replace_substring(l, a, b):
    return strx(l).replace( strx(a), strx(b) ).split(', ')
```

Comment: Only if you can reliably encode each possible list element as a unique character.

Answer (score 0):

Using [xrange](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange) is a simple improvement that will speed up your code. `xrange` returns a generator, so performance improvements will be particualy noticeable for long lists. But even with your really short test code I get a decent increase.

Using timeit:

```
replace_subsequence        0.337936162949, 100000 runs
replace_subsequence_xrange 0.275990962982, 100000 runs
```

Additionally you should assign a variable to `len(a)` outside of the loop, this way you won't keep calling the `len()` function. This will also yield a significant speedup.