# replace consecutive values of a list if they are equal to one single value of another list

Tags: python, list, nlp, token

For instance, given a list *article_list* and *disease_list*, which are defined as follows:

```
article_list = ['Tricuspid', 'valve', 'regurgitation', 'and', 'lithium', 'carbonate', 
               'toxicity', 'in', 'a', 'newborn', 'infant', '.']

disease_list = ['Tricuspid valve regurgitation', 'lithium carbonate', 'toxicity']
```

As you can see article_list is a list of tokens of an article. However, I would like to tokenize disease names (which often consist of several words) as one token instead of several. That means to replace the tokens of article_list with the tokens in disease list on the right places.

The function should be something like this

```py
def insert_disease_tokens(article_list, disease_list):
    # do something
```

```
print(insert_disease_tokens(article_list, disease_list))
>>> ['Tricuspid valve regurgitation', 'and', 'lithium carbonate','toxicity', 'in', 'a', 'newborn', 'infant', '.']
```

Any idea with an efficient way to do that in Python? I only came up with unnecessarily complicated solutions.

Comment: how do you tokenize in the first place? maybe insert '_' instead of ' ' in the original data for which you dont want white space tokenization and then after tokenizing you can replace the ' ' with spaces

Comment: I did not tokenize the data. I do not even know if the dataset was tokenized based on whitespaces. The only thing I did is to collect data about known diseases. I want to keep the tokenization the way it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented just reverse engineering that suggestion gives the solution. basically, make data, replace space with "_" and then do white space tokenization. this won't work if the data contains "_" on its own.

```
article_list = ['Tricuspid', 'valve', 'regurgitation', 'and', 'lithium', 'carbonate', 
               'toxicity', 'in', 'a', 'newborn', 'infant', '.']

disease_list = ['Tricuspid valve regurgitation', 'lithium carbonate', 'toxicity']

data = ' '.join(article_list)

for disease in disease_list:
    d = disease.replace(' ', '_')
    data = data.replace(disease, d)
    
tokens = data.split()

for i,t in enumerate(tokens):
    t = t.replace('_', ' ')
    tokens[i] = t
    
print(tokens)
"""
['Tricuspid valve regurgitation', 'and', 'lithium carbonate', 'toxicity', 
 'in', 'a', 'newborn', 'infant', '.']
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all the spaces in both the text and the disease with a placeholder temporarily, then control how it gets replaced back (in case of normal text leave placeholder while in the ngrams to be merged return to space), then split back to original list format by splitting by that placeholder. Pad start and end with the placeholder to include the cases of sentence starting or ending with a term.

As placeholder you can use '_' as @Ritwick Jha suggested or as I did in the example '__' to be a bit more sure it won't naturally occur in texts or terms.

```
import re

def insert_disease_tokens(article_list_, disease_list_, ph='__'):
    # join to one string using placeholders and pad with placeholders
    article_list_ = ph + ph.join(article_list_) + ph
    # for each disease: if its (placeholder-replaced) version occurs in the text, replace it by space-separated version
    for d in disease_list_:
        article_list_ = re.sub(ph + d.replace(" ", ph) + ph, ph + d + ph, article_list_)
    # split by the placeholder, meaning everything will get split except the space-separated found terms, also remove padding again
    return article_list_[len(ph):-len(ph)].split(ph)

article_list = insert_disease_tokens(article_list, disease_list)
```

Which returns:

```
> ['Tricuspid valve regurgitation', 'and', 'lithium carbonate', 'toxicity', 'in', 'a', 'newborn', 'infant', '.']
```

You can of course use a completely different approach as this is not a string-specific problem but rather a general one (how to replace specific sub-sequences in a list) and for large data that will probably be much more efficient, but the indexing can get pretty complicated. Check out e.g. [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683745/how-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-sub-sequence-in-a-list-in-python).